# Nuxt layout does not update when current path changes

Tags: nuxt.js

My default layout includes a navigation bar.

My navigation bar rendering changes depending on the current url. (For example, the current section is highlighted)

I am using `this.$router.currentRoute.path` to get the current path.

If I use normal `<a href=...>...</a>` tags, then it works fine.

However when using `nuxt-link` for client side navigation, the layout doesn't update.

How can I fix this?

Maybe if there is a way to listen on route changes, then I can trigger the change?

Answer (score -1):

In the mounted method of the component, I can do

```
    this.$router.afterEach((to, from) => {
        this.path = this.$router.currentRoute.path
    });
```

Which will update `this.path` to the new url path.

Components in the default layout will then properly update themselves if they use the `path` data value.